# Segfault on QTextStream in singleton destructor (static object, __tcf_0)

Tags: qt, c++11, static, segmentation-fault, destructor

I'm having a hard time figuring out what's causing this segfault.
According to [my research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227020/what-is-function-tcf-0-seen-when-using-gprof-and-g), it's related to some static variable in my code (see *__tcf_0* in the stack trace below). 
The fact is, I have only one static variable in my code, which is the instance of a singleton class (see below).

This code seems correct to me, yet when the program terminates, a segfault is thrown in `~Logger()` (line `qDebug() << "Segfault";`). The same thing happens when I try to `delete` a `QTextStream*` for example. However, printing out to the console using the standard `cout` works perfectly, as well as doing anything else using the **standard library**. It seems **it only affects some Qt classes**.

**EDIT:** it seems that the problem comes from the `QTextStream` class. Indeed, `qDebug()` uses it. Other classes which don't use it don't cause a segfault.

Here are the files and the stack trace:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "Logger.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Logger::getInstance(); // Create Logger instance

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Singleton.h**

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

template <class T>
class Singleton
{
protected:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;


public:
    static T &getInstance()
    {
        static T instance; // <----- static variable here
        return instance;
    }
};

#endif // SINGLETON_H
```

**Logger.h**

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include "Singleton.h"

class Logger : public Singleton<Logger>
{
    friend class Singleton<Logger>;

private:
    Logger();
    ~Logger();
};

#endif // LOGGER_H
```

**Logger.cpp**

```
#include "Logger.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

Logger::Logger() : Singleton<Logger>()
{
}

Logger::~Logger()
{
    std::cout << "It works" << std::endl;
    qDebug() << "Segfault"; // <----- segfault here
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
0   msvcrt!_msize   C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll      0x75cff4fc  
1   ??          0x20d0ea8   
2   msvcrt!.dllonexit   C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll      0x75cff52c  
3   (anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS_globalInstance::Holder::~Holder        47  0x6b971717  
4   ??          0xd8fc7add  
5   mingw_onexit    C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\Qt5Cored.dll      0x6b9ae548  
6   atexit  C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\Qt5Cored.dll      0x6b9ae5af  
7   (anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS_globalInstance::innerFunction      47  0x6b971779  
8   QGlobalStatic<QCoreGlobalData, (* (anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS_globalInstance::innerFunction), (* & (anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS_globalInstance::guard)>::operator()(void)      128 0x6b971917  
9   QCoreGlobalData::instance       63  0x6b9718f2  
10  QTextCodec::codecForLocale      680 0x6b97c475  
11  QTextStreamPrivate::reset       399 0x6b8ba6be  
12  QTextStreamPrivate::QTextStreamPrivate      330 0x6b8ba3ce  
13  QTextStream::QTextStream        954 0x6b8bb69b  
14  QDebug::Stream::Stream      66  0x6ba17d27  
15  QDebug::QDebug      78  0x6ba17dfa  
16  QMessageLogger::debug       359 0x6b78cd0e  
17  Logger::~Logger Logger.cpp  13  0x401700    
18  __tcf_0 Singleton.h 15  0x40168c    
19  msvcrt!isspace  C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll      0x75cfc3e9  
20  msvcrt!_cexit   C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll      0x75d037df  
21  ??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is simple, `QApplication` gets destroyed before your singleton destruction, and `qDebug` needs `QApplication` object to get current text codec.

This is perfect example why singletons are problematic.

Change code in such way that singleton is cleared before `QApplication` object, or make it eternal (this may not solve problem completely sicnce some other object could use your singleton after `QApplication` was destroyed).

Comment: Yes I was about to post the answer. I was still hesitating about why `QTextCodec::codecForLocale()` would return `NULL` but you confirm my hypothesis. Thank you. Indeed you're right, singletons are evil... I spent hours to figure this out. I've learned my lesson.